# Как вычислить width, используя calc?

Tags: javascript, html, css

а не через js

то есть не задавать  wrap.style.setProperty('--w', w + 'px');

а тут всё учесть ( width: var(--w, 100vw);)
28 строка css

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
const setWidth = () => {
  let w = wrap.offsetWidth;
  wrap.style.setProperty('--w', w + 'px');
}
setWidth();
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  setWidth();
});
```

```css
.container {
     padding: 0 30px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 1190px;
}
 .wrap {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
     column-gap: 24px;
}
 .item {
     background-color: #eee;
     padding: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 108px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .item {
     position: relative;
}
 .item::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 25px;
     left: 0;
     width: var(--w, 100vw);
     height: 65px;
     background-position: left 110px bottom;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/_Xm.svg');
     background-size: contain;
}
 .item:nth-child(even)::before {
     transform: translateX(calc(0px - 50% - 12px));
}
 .item:first-child::before {
     left: 88px;
     background-position: left 10px bottom;
}
 .item:first-child::after {
     position: absolute;
     content: ' ';
     bottom: 38px;
     left: 40px;
     width: 48px;
     height: 48px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: #c8d1f2;
}
 *, *::after, *::before {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>title 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum debitis inventore suscipit pariatur, rem distinctio consectetur sequi. Voluptates laborum eos dicta laboriosam quia cupiditate rem beatae non, debitis laudantium enim?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>title 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum debitis inventore suscipit pariatur, rem distinctio consectetur sequi. Voluptates laborum eos dicta laboriosam quia cupiditate rem beatae non, debitis laudantium enim?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: на текущий момент вообще ни чего не понятно, пожалуйста, дополните вопрос

Comment: дополнен вопрос

Comment: пожалуйста предоставте минимально воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно для данного случая, достаточно указать сумму удвоенной ширины родителя и ширины отступа между колонками сетки:

```css
width: calc( 200% + 24px ); /* column-gap: 24px; */
```

Если добавим переменную, то сможем одновременно: и устанавливать отступ в сетке и прокидывать значение до нужного псевдоэлемента:

```css
*, *::after, *::before { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1190px;
}

.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  --col-gap: 24px;
  column-gap: var(--col-gap);
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 108px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(200% + var(--col-gap));
  height: 65px;
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/_Xm.svg');
  background-position: left 110px bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.item:nth-child(even)::before {
  transform: translateX(calc(0px - 50% - 12px));
}

.item:first-child::before {
  left: 88px;
  background-position: left 10px bottom;
}

.item:first-child::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 38px;
  left: 40px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #c8d1f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>title 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum debitis inventore suscipit pariatur, rem distinctio consectetur sequi. Voluptates laborum eos dicta laboriosam quia cupiditate rem beatae non, debitis laudantium enim?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>title 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum debitis inventore suscipit pariatur, rem distinctio consectetur sequi. Voluptates laborum eos dicta laboriosam quia cupiditate rem beatae non, debitis laudantium enim?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```